Uniqueness of Harder-Narasimhan filtration for coherent sheafs
I am reading the following lecture notes https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/205notes/Lecture20-HarderNarasimhan.pdf on the Harder-Narasimhan filtration. I am having trouble understanding the inductive step regarding the uniqueness part of the Harder-Narasimhan filtration:
It is proven that $\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon^{\prime}_1$. Then by the inductive hypothesis it is clear that $\varepsilon_2/\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon^{\prime}_2/\varepsilon^{\prime}_1$. But how can one conclude from this that $\varepsilon_2 = \varepsilon^{\prime}_2$?

But how does one conclude that $\varepsilon_2/\varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon^{\prime}_2/\varepsilon_1$ implies $\varepsilon_2 = \varepsilon^{\prime}_2$. I mean I have the isomorphisms theorems for modules which should also be true in any abelian category. However one needs that $\varepsilon^{\prime}_2 \subseteq \varepsilon_2$ to conclude that $0 = \varepsilon_2 /\varepsilon^{\prime}_2 = (\varepsilon_2/\varepsilon_1)/(\varepsilon^{\prime}_2/\varepsilon_1)$

The key is that we have equality $\mathcal{E}_1 = \mathcal{E}_1'$, not just isomorphism. As in, there are equal as subsheaves of $\mathcal{E}$. There is a 1-to-1 correspondance between subsheaves of $\mathcal{E}/\mathcal{E}_1$ and subsheaves of $\mathcal{E}$ that contain $\mathcal{E}_1$.
Since induction tells us that $\mathcal{E}_2/\mathcal{E}_1 = \mathcal{E}_2'/\mathcal{E}_1$ are equal (as subsheaves of $\mathcal{E}/\mathcal{E}_1$), this implies that $\mathcal{E}_2 = \mathcal{E}_2'$.
